# Google Jam 2009. C. Welcome to Code Jam. Can't understand Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The original link of the problem is here: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/90101/dashboard#s=p2&a=2

In simple words we need to find how many times the string S="welcome to code jam" appears as a sub-sequence of given string S, e.g.
S="welcome to code jam"
T="wweellccoommee to code qps jam"

I know the theory but not good at DP in practice. Would you please explain step-by-step process to solve this DP problem on example and why it works?

Answer (score 1):

To explain it in simple terms :

```
         if(S(i) == T(k))

           Subseq(i,k) = Subseq(i+1,k+1) + Subseq(i,k+1)

         else Subseq(i,k) = Subseq(i,k+1)
```

where i denotes substring S[i to end]

where k denotes substring T[k to end]

where Subseq(i,k) = number of subsequences of S[i to end] in T[k to end]

where S(i) = character at ith index in S

where T(k) = character at kth index in T

Ans = Subseq(0,0)

**Explanation: -**

1.>

```
  if(S(i) == T(k))

           Subseq(i,k) = Subseq(i+1,k+1) + Subseq(i,k+1)
```

if S(i) == T(k) then

a.>

index k might be part of subsequence of S[i to end] in T[k to end]

hence, number of subsequence start with k of S[i to end] in T[k to end] will be equal to number of subsequence  of S[i+1 to end] in T[k+1 to end]

b.>

subsequence might not start with k in that case we need to evaluate S[i to end] in 
T[j+1 to end]

conclusion : As `a.>` & `b.>` generate completely different subsequences hence to evaluate all possible subsequences we need to evaluate sum of them.

2.>

```
else Subseq(i,k) = Subseq(i,k+1)
```

opposite to case `1.>` here `a.>` is impossible as S(i) != T(k) so no subsequence can start
with k hence we are left with only `b.>` as possibilty.

**Example:-**

```
S = "abc"  T = "aabc"
```

We have to calculate Subseq(0,0)

from above formula :-

1.>

i = 0

k = 0

```
if(S(0)==T(0)) = true => Subseq(0,0) = Subseq(1,1) + Subseq(1,2)
```

now we have to Subseq(1,1) & Subseq(1,2)

2.>

i = 1

k = 1

```
if(S(1)==T(1)) = false => Subseq(1,1) = Subseq(1,2)
```

As you can see Subseq(1,2) is used in both derived equation so i will evaluate it only once

3.>

i = 1

k = 2

```
if(S(1)==T(2)) = true => Subseq(1,2) = Subseq(2,3) + Subseq(1,3)
```

4.>

i = 1

k = 3

```
if(S(1)==T(3)) = false => Subseq(1,3) = Subseq(1,4)


as we know T(4) = null hence Subseq(1,4) = 0   hence Subseq(1,3) = 0
```

5.>

i = 2

k = 3

```
 if(S(2)==T(3)) = true => Subseq(2,3) = Subseq(3,4) + Subseq(2,4)


    Subseq(3,4) = 1 as S(3) = null & S(4) == null and null string is always subsequence of null string

    Subseq(2,4) = 0 as T[end] = null & S[2 to end] ! = null so S[2 to end] is not subsequence of T[end]

    Subseq(2,3) = 1 + 0 = 1
```

6.>

using `5.>` and `4.>` and `3.>`

```
Subseq(2,3) = 1

Subseq(1,3) = 0

Subseq(1,2) = Subseq(2,3) + Subseq(1,3)

Subseq(1,2) = 1 + 0 = 1
```

7.>

using `6.>` and `2.>` and `1.>`

```
Subseq(1,2) = 1

Subseq(1,1) = Subseq(1,2) = 1

Subseq(0,0) = Subseq(1,1) + Subseq(1,2) = 2
```

**Conclusion**

```
Subseq(0,0) = 2 which means S="abc" appears 2 times as distinct subsequence in T = "aabc"
```

Now we know how to solve the problem the question is can we do it faster?

Answer to above question is Dynamic Programming .

As we have seen in above example we used Subseq(1,2) two times once for Subseq(1,1) & once

for Subseq(0,0) so it would be usefull if we compute Subseq(1,2) only once and store it in

table for later use.

So DP suggests that we precompute all values which are below in heirarchy of current

sub-problem before evaluting current problem , doing so we can prevent redudant

computations of same sub-problems.

Hence in above example we can evaluate Subseq(1,2) & Subseq(2,3) before and store it in

2-D table and use directly while computing Subseq(0,0)

Now comes the question which are the sub-problems in lowest heirarchy ?

In this case we notice the equations:-

```
Subseq(i,k) = Subseq(i+1,k+1) + Subseq(i,k+1)

or

Subseq(i,k) = Subseq(i,k+1)
```

As we can clearly notice each problem (i,k) is only dependent on (i,k+1) and (i+1,k+1)

so both i & k are dependent on values which are greater or equal than themselves.

Use the above observation we can compute 2-d table (i,k) starting from higher values

of i & j for all possibilities and the entry (0,0) will be the solution to the problem

**Pseudo Code** : -

```
lenS = length(S)

lenT = length(T)

// Table to store subsequence count for all sub-problems 

Subseq[lenS+1][lenT+1];

// Empty string is subseq of Empty string 

Subseq[lenS][lenT] = 1

// NoN-Emtpy string is not subsequence of empty string

for(i = 0 ; i<lenS ; i++)
   Subseq[i][lenT] = 0


// Emtpy string is always subsequence of Non-empty string 

for(k = 0 ; k<lenT ; k++)
   Subseq[lenS][k] = 1


// Evaluate table from higher values to lower values

for(i = lenS-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {


for(k = lenT-1 ; k>=0 ; k--) {



   if(S[i]==T[k]) 
       Subseq[i][k] = Subseq[i+1][k+1] + Subseq[i][k+1]

   else Subseq[i][k] = Subseq[i][k+1]         


}



}

// Answer

print Subseq[0][0]
```

**Note:**

In above pseudo code for all values of (i,k) we already have the values of required sub-problems

Please comment if u donot get any of the above explanation

Comment: Thanks Vikram. Can you explain why in step a. you use indices i+1 and k+1. I don't understand the essence of these indices with +1.

Comment: in a.> Subseq(i+1,k+1) denotes the no of subsequences of S[i+1 to end] in T[k+1 to end] which will be same as number of subsequence of S[i to end] in T[i to end] which start at T[k].

Comment: eg. S = "ab" T = "abb" as S(0) == T(0) Subseq(ab,abb) starting at T(0) =   Subseq(b,bb) which are 2 in this case Subseq(ab,abb) are {0,1} and {0,2} and Subseq(b,bb) = {1} and {2}

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution in java that is much easier. We move backwards in string S 1 char at a time. In this particular example DP-array passes the following states: 100(initially)->110->120->122->124 where 4 is the answer but I don't understand this solution either:

```
    char[] T = "AABB".toCharArray();
    char[] S = "AB".toCharArray();

    int[] d = new int[S.length + 1];
    d[0] = 1;

    for (char c : T) {
        for (int i = S.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c == S[i]) {
                d[i + 1] += d[i];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(d[S.length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The java implementation is another approach to solve the problem and is actually more space efficient to my surprise.

Explanation:-

```
d[i][k] = no of subsequence of S[0 to i] in T[0 to k]

d[i-1][k] = no of subsequnce of S[0 to i-1] in T[0 to k]

if(S[i]==T[k])
   d[i][k] = d[i][k-1] + d[i-1][k-1]

else d[i][k] = d[i][k-1]
```

The above is what the code is doing

if u notice it properly it is the same approach as my but in reverse order of string